# Using a webView to save a page on a Service

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to store webpages using the method "saveWebArchive" from a webView in a Service but I get an error saying that *"A WebView method was called on thread 'IntentService[OffLineSaverService]'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads".*

Which is fair enough but... is there any way to do it?

```
public class OffLineSaverService extends IntentService {    

public OffLineSaverService() {
    super("OffLineSaverService");

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    webViewSaver = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {      
    Log.w("Service", "Service started");

    webViewSaver.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            final String fileName = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "myfile.html";
            view.saveWebArchive(fileName);

    });

    webViewSaver.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
}
}
```

In that code I am just saving one page but the idea is going though a list of links and save all the pages.

I am not sure if I can use the runOnUiThread() method, but if I do, would I be overloading the Ui thread?

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. Have you been able to access WebView methods from a service? Is this possible at all? Did you succeed?